# Getting "PDF generation failed. Check the page markup is valid." Error from tables?

Tags: visualforce, pdf, html, renderas

I'm working on what should be a relatively simple PDF Quote page using visualforce.

For some reason I have run into an issue where no matter what I try I keep getting an error that the PDF Generation has failed.'

Any ideas why?

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardController="Opportunity" extensions="ConveniencePricingExtension" standardStylesheets="false" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false">
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.PureCSS, 'pure-release-0.6.0/pure-min.css')}"/>
<head>
<style>
.pull-left {
  float: left !important;
}
.pull-right {
  float: right !important;
}
.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.page-break {
    display:block;
    page-break-after:always;
}
.full {
    width: 100%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page-break">
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!Opportunity != null}">
    <table class="full">
       <tr>
            <td class="pull-left">
                <h1>{!thisOpp.Name}</h1>
            </td>
            <td class="pull-right">
                <h1>RTO</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>            
            <td class="pull-left">
                {!thisAccount.Name}
                <br />
                {!thisAccount.BillingStreet}
                <br />
                {!thisAccount.BillingCity}, {!thisAccount.BillingState} {!thisAccount.BillingPostalCode}
            </td>

            <td class="pull-right">
                Created Date: {!nowEST}
                <br />
                Opportunity Number: {!thisOpp.Opportunity_Number__c}
                <br />
                Terms: {!contractYears} Years
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <br />
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!selectedProducts_OneTime.size != 0 || customContentList_OneTime.size != 0}">
        <div class="pure-u-5-5">
            <table class="pure-table pure-table-horizontal">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="4">One Time Fees</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Qty</th>
                        <th>Unit Price</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <apex:repeat Rendered="{!selectedProducts_OneTime.size != 0}" value="{!selectedProducts_OneTime}" var="p">        
                        <tr>
                            <td>{!p.Product.Name}</td>
                            <td>{!unitCount}</td>
                            <td>
                                <apex:outputText value="${0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                                    <apex:param value="{!IF(p.Product.IgnoreDiscount__c == true, ROUND(p.Price, 2),ROUND(p.Price - (p.Price*(discountPercent /100)),2))}" />
                                </apex:outputText>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <apex:outputText value="${0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                                    <apex:param value="{!IF(p.Product.IgnoreDiscount__c == true, ROUND(p.Price*unitCount, 2),ROUND((p.Price - (p.Price*(discountPercent /100))*unitCount),2))}" />
                                </apex:outputText>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </apex:repeat>
                    <apex:repeat Rendered="{!customContentList_OneTime.size != 0}" value="{!customContentList_OneTime}" var="p">        
                        <tr>
                            <td>{!p.Name}</td>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>
                                <apex:outputText value="${0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                                    <apex:param value="{!ROUND(p.oneTimeFee, 2)}" />
                                </apex:outputText>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <apex:outputText value="${0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                                    <apex:param value="{!ROUND(p.oneTimeFee- (p.oneTimeFee*(discountPercent /100)),2)}" />
                                </apex:outputText>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <br />
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!selectedProducts_Monthly.size != 0 || customContentList_Monthly.size != 0}">
        <div class="pure-u-5-5">
            <table class="pure-table pure-table-horizontal">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="4">Monthly Fees</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Qty</th>
                        <th>Unit Price</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <apex:repeat Rendered="{!selectedProducts_Monthly.size != 0}" value="{!selectedProducts_Monthly}" var="p">        
                        <tr>
                            <td>{!p.Product.Name}</td>
                            <td>{!unitCount}</td>
                            <td>
                                <apex:outputText value="${0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                                    <apex:param value="{!IF(p.Product.IgnoreDiscount__c == true, ROUND(p.Price, 2),ROUND(p.Price - (p.Price*(discountPercent /100)),2))}" />
                                </apex:outputText>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <apex:outputText value="${0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                                    <apex:param value="{!IF(p.Product.IgnoreDiscount__c == true, ROUND(p.Price*unitCount, 2),ROUND((p.Price - (p.Price*(discountPercent /100))*unitCount),2))}" />
                                </apex:outputText>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </apex:repeat>
                    <apex:repeat Rendered="{!customContentList_Monthly.size != 0}" value="{!customContentList_Monthly}" var="p">        
                        <tr>
                            <td>{!p.Name}</td>
                            <td>{!unitCount}</td>
                            <td>
                                <apex:outputText value="${0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                                    <apex:param value="{!ROUND(p.monthlyFee *unitCount, 2)}" />
                                </apex:outputText>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <apex:outputText value="${0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                                    <apex:param value="{!ROUND((p.monthlyFee - (p.monthlyFee *(discountPercent /100)))*unitCount,2)}" />
                                </apex:outputText>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <br />
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!selectedProducts_Yearly.size != 0 || customContentList_Yearly.size != 0}">
        <div class="pure-u-5-5">
            <table class="pure-table pure-table-horizontal">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="4">Yearly Fees</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Qty</th>
                        <th>Unit Price</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <apex:repeat Rendered="{!selectedProducts_Yearly.size != 0}" value="{!selectedProducts_Yearly}" var="p">        
                        <tr>
                            <td>{!p.Product.Name}</td>
                            <td>{!unitCount}</td>
                            <td>
                                <apex:outputText value="${0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                                    <apex:param value="{!IF(p.Product.IgnoreDiscount__c == true, ROUND(p.Price, 2),ROUND(p.Price - (p.Price*(discountPercent /100)),2))}" />
                                </apex:outputText>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <apex:outputText value="${0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                                    <apex:param value="{!IF(p.Product.IgnoreDiscount__c == true, ROUND((p.Price*unitCount)*12, 2),ROUND((((p.Price - (p.Price*(discountPercent /100)))*unitCount))*12,2))}" />
                                </apex:outputText>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </apex:repeat>
                    <apex:repeat Rendered="{!customContentList_Yearly.size != 0}" value="{!customContentList_Yearly}" var="p">        
                        <tr>
                            <td>{!p.Name}</td>
                            <td>{!unitCount}</td>
                            <td>
                                <apex:outputText value="${0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                                    <apex:param value="{!ROUND((p.yearlyFee *unitCount)*12, 2)}" />
                                </apex:outputText>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <apex:outputText value="${0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                                    <apex:param value="{!ROUND(((p.yearlyFee - (p.yearlyFee *(discountPercent /100)))*unitCount)*12,2)}" />
                                </apex:outputText>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table class="pure-table">
            <tr>
                <th>TERMS AND CONDITIONS</th>
                <td>Review the <a href="http://www.readytrainingonline.com/terms/">Ready Training Online (RTO) Terms and Conditions</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>AUTHORIZED SIGNATURE</th>
                <td>By signing below, the signee hereby acknowledges and accepts the terms and
conditions of the Agreement, including without limitation, Ready Training Online’s
(RTO) Terms and Conditions as set forth in this agreement and online at the RTO
Website.
The undersigned represents that they have the authority to bind {!thisAccount.Name} to the terms of this Agreement. The terms of this Agreement are the
Confidential Information of RTO.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: could you remove renderAs="pdf" and see what's going on page when that's not pdf?

Comment: @kurunve Whe I remove the renderAs="pdf" it acts as expected, displaying information as necessary.

Comment: then I would recommend you to remove parts of page one by one until that starts rendering and figure out where does that fail (at which block or line)

Comment: I have also face this issue many time in PDF generation. So what i suggest remove your css at top and then try . It will surely help.

Comment: @TusharSharma the reference to Pure.css or the CSS in the <style> tags?

Comment: first go with css in style tag because renderAs=Pdf does not support many styling. like position,table border etc.

Answer (score 3):

### Edited to be more like an answer.

There could be many answers to this problem.
Ultimately "Check your css!"

I received this error earlier today and isolated right down to a height tag in my CSS class, 2nd time I have found it in my "min-height" tag in one of my css classes.
by half splitting I found these 2.
But they were red herrings.

removing them fixed the issue temporarily.

```
.pdf_data-table div{
    height:50px; //REMOVE THIS LINE AND EVERYTHING WORKS
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

then

```
.pdf_pageheader{
    font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    table-layout: fixed;
    padding: 5px;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    min-height:87px; //REMOVE THIS LINE AND EVERYTHING WORKS AGAIN
    width:inherit;
    overflow: auto;
    background:{!$Setup.Variables__c.Color__c};
}
```

the actual issue was:

```
.table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

I needed to remove the dot at the front.

```
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

I was able to add back my height statements.